# how to delete the lines which contains character that start after a specific string and ends with character found in a file in java?

Tags: java-8

I have a file with abc.txt

### abc.txt

hhjj

myhome _ dfdfdsfds
fdsfds

dfdfdsfdsd
fdsfdsf
dfdfdsfdsdfdsfd

dfdsfds

dfdsfds
_

hhhh
jjj
kkkk

The character after myhome could be any character it could be special characters,letters or numbers.I need to find the character after myhome and delete the lines in between and that end with character. In my file I have mentioned as '*' after myhome and with '*'.

The output should be

### abc.txt

hhjj

hhhh
jjj
kkkk

I have tried how to read a file by line by line

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("abc.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Could anyone help ??

Answer (score 0):

**Structure**

[image: project]

**App.java**

```
package main;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        App app = new App();
        app.parseFile();
    }

    void parseFile() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Reading from package main
        File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/main/abc.txt").getFile());
        // If you want to read from HDD, for example :
        // File file = new File("/home/user/abc.txt"); or File file = new File("c:\\abc.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(input.nextLine());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        input.close();
        String text = sb.toString();
        text = text
            .replace(
                text.substring(
                    text.indexOf("myhome _"),
                    text.lastIndexOf('_')+1
                ),
                ""
            )
            .replace("\n\n", "\n");
        Path newFile = Paths.get("abc_new.txt");
        Files.write(newFile, Arrays.asList(text.split("\n")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

New written file will be in project folder.